# Appstore Connect App Transfer Error - How to reset email under test information

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

Trying to transfer app in Appstore connect but it says  - "You must first remove all builds and testers from the app you want transferred and clear each information field below Test Information."

Inside Test information, there are first name, last name and email. All of them are mandatory. I have saved blank space in first and last name, but email field has validation of correct email and don't take blank space. How do i reset email field.

Answer (score 0):

The step which wasn't obvious to me which ultimately got the check to a green checkmark was going into "Test Information" and deleting all of the entered data. Just blank it out and ignore the yellow warning message.

Comment: Confirmed as of Sept 6, 2023, this is still the correct solution. I mean, come on! Removing the builds as instructed on the Transfer App page is not enough. You have to guess, on your own volition, that clearing some general info fields is the magic key that allows app transfers. I thought Apple's position was that they do a lot of work for their 30% cut.